# Display a two dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an x by y board of numbers stored in a two dimensional array in java that I would like to print out to the user in a nice formatted manner.  Would there be an easy way to do this in java?

Here is how I build my board:

```
board = new int[TotRow][TotCol];
```

Comment: Please put in some code that explains your case

Answer (score 2):

You might prefer the one line, because it's easy, [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) the Javadoc says (in part),

> This method is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number to be padded properly as well use `String.format()`,

```
for (int i = 0; i < TotRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TotCol; j++) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%3d", board[i][j]) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Notice that I have used `%3d` for formatting, you can use format as required by you

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: inner loop `System.out.print` instead

Comment: This may work (after changing the first `println` to `print`), but I tend to avoid using tabs because you really don't have any control over how they work or whether they do anything at all.

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: Note also that there's a big difference between this answer and Nitin's: using `String.format("%3d")` causes the numbers to be right-justified in each column (i.e. the low-order digits line up), while this left-justifies them (the high-order digits line up).  Which one the OP wants is a matter of preference, but most people are used to seeing tables of integers right-justified, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the `board` `two dimensional` array like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't like relying on tabs, I'd like to mention some approaches that don't rely on them.

If you know that all of the numbers in the table are nonnegative numbers of, say, 4 digits or less, you can use `String.format` in a manner similar to Nitin's answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TotRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TotCol; j++) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%4d ", board[i][j]));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The `%4d` means to format the number using a width of 4 characters, and pad with blanks on the left if the number takes fewer than 4 characters to print.  Thus, if there aren't any 5-digit or longer numbers, each `print` will print exactly 5 characters--a 4-character field for the number, and a space after the number.  This will make everything line up, as long as none of the numbers is too large.  If you do get a number that takes more than 4 characters, the formatting will get messed up.

Here's a way to adjust the column width so that it's just large enough to hold all the values in the table, and works fine if there are negative numbers:

```
int maxWidth = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < TotRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TotCol; j++) {
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, Integer.toString(board[i][j]).length());
    }
}
String format = "%" + maxWidth + "d ";
for (int i = 0; i < TotRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TotCol; j++) {
        System.out.print(String.format(format, board[i][j]));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Note:** not tested

Answer (score 0):

You basically just use a nested loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```